# Unicode Dict Keys Issue

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, python-3.5, python-unicode

Using python 3.5. From my understand all strings should be unicode by default. Why are these unicode key names being encoded using ascii?

```
row_map = {
            'α-Pinene': 7,
            'β-Pinene': 8,
            'Terpinolene': 9,
            'Geraniol': 10,
            'α-Terpinene': 11,
            'γ-Terpinene': 12,
            'Camphene': 13,
            'Linalool': 14,
            'd-Limonene': 15,
            'Citral': 16,
            'Myrcene': 17,
            'α-Terpineol': 18,
            'Citronellol': 19,
            'dl-Menthol': 20,
            '1-Borneol': 21,
            '2-Piperidone': 22,
            'β-Caryophyllene': 23,
            'α-Humulene': 24,
            'Caryophyllene Oxide': 5,
        }
        with open("log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print(row_map, file=f)
        print(open("log.txt", "rb").read())
```

Here are the results writing these keys to utf-8 text.
**log.txt**

```
dict_keys([
    'Terpinolene', 
    'Camphene', 
    'Myrcene', 
    'Î±-Terpineol', 
    'd-Limonene', 
    '2-Piperidone', 
    'Î³-Terpinene', 
    'Geraniol', 
    'Linalool', 
    'Î±-Humulene', 
    'Î±-Pinene', 
    'Î²-Caryophyllene', 
    'Î²-Pinene', 
    'Caryophyllene Oxide', 
    'Citronellol', 
    '1-Borneol', 
    'Citral', 
    'Î±-Terpinene', 
    'dl-Menthol'])
```

**EDIT:** [Here](https://drive.google.com/a/zenlogic.us/file/d/0B7g7N-nhGWa9RE1FaXE0NE5FMEE/view?usp=sharing) is the actual txt file. So one can verify it is not my viewer.

**EDIT #2:** Please take a look at this funkiness.

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> row_map = {
...                 'α-Pinene': 7,
...                 'β-Pinene': 8,
...                 'Terpinolene': 9,
...                 'Geraniol': 10,
...                 'α-Terpinene': 11,
...                 'γ-Terpinene': 12,
...                 'Camphene': 13,
...                 'Linalool': 14,
...                 'd-Limonene': 15,
...                 'Citral': 16,
...                 'Myrcene': 17,
...                 'α-Terpineol': 18,
...                 'Citronellol': 19,
...                 'dl-Menthol': 20,
...                 '1-Borneol': 21,
...                 '2-Piperidone': 22,
...                 'β-Caryophyllene': 23,
...                 'α-Humulene': 24,
...                 'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25,
...             }
>>> row_map
{'Citral': 16, 'd-Limonene': 15, 'Myrcene': 17, 'Camphene': 13, 'ß-Caryophyllene': 23, 'α-Terpinene': 11, 'Linalool': 14, 'α-Humulene': 24, '1-Borneol': 21, 'Citronellol': 19, 'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25, 'α-Terpineol': 18, 'α-Pinene': 7, '2-Piperidone': 22, 'dl-Menthol': 20, 'Terpinolene': 9, 'ß-Pinene': 8, 'Geraniol': 10, '?-Terpinene': 12}
>>> from strains.models import Terpene
>>> Terpene.row_map
{'Citral': 16, 'd-Limonene': 15, 'Myrcene': 17, 'Camphene': 13, 'α-Terpinene': 11, 'Linalool': 14, 'α-Humulene': 24, '1-Borneol': 21, 'Citronellol': 19, 'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25, 'α-Terpineol': 18, 'α-Pinene': 7, '\u03b2-Caryophyllene': 23, '2-Piperidone': 22, 'dl-Menthol': 20, 'Terpinolene': 9, '\u03b3-Terpinene': 12, 'Geraniol': 10, '\u03b2-Pinene': 8}
>>>
```

I copied this from the problem code and pasted this into the shell. Note how the pasted dict has automatically replaced anything it couldnt encode with a **?**.

Notice how the same exact dict that is an attribute of the Terpene obj escaped the unicode!

Here is the Terpene Object's `row_map`

```
class Terpene(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    short_desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    long_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    aroma = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    effects = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

row_map = {
    'α-Pinene': 7,
    'β-Pinene': 8,
    'Terpinolene': 9,
    'Geraniol': 10,
    'α-Terpinene': 11,
    'γ-Terpinene': 12,
    'Camphene': 13,
    'Linalool': 14,
    'd-Limonene': 15,
    'Citral': 16,
    'Myrcene': 17,
    'α-Terpineol': 18,
    'Citronellol': 19,
    'dl-Menthol': 20,
    '1-Borneol': 21,
    '2-Piperidone': 22,
    'β-Caryophyllene': 23,
    'α-Humulene': 24,
    'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25,
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here is the binary read from the problem code:

```
b"{'\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb1-Terpinene': 11, 'Geraniol': 10, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb1-Pinene': 7, 'dl-Menthol': 20, 'Myrcene': 17, 'Citral': 16, 'Citronellol': 19, 'Camphene': 13, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb3-Terpinene': 12, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb1-Terpineol': 18, '1-Borneol': 21, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb1-Humulene': 24, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb2-Caryophyllene': 23, '\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb2-Pinene': 8, '2-Piperidone': 22, 'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25, 'Linalool': 14, 'Terpinolene': 9, 'd-Limonene': 15}\r\n"
```

Here is the binary read from the Terpene Object row_map:

```
b"{'Geraniol': 10, '\xce\xb2-Caryophyllene': 23, '\xce\xb1-Pinene': 7, 'Citral': 16, '\xce\xb3-Terpinene': 12, 'Myrcene': 17, 'Camphene': 13, '\xce\xb1-Terpinene': 11, 'dl-Menthol': 20, '1-Borneol': 21, '\xce\xb1-Humulene': 24, '\xce\xb2-Pinene': 8, 'd-Limonene': 15, 'Citronellol': 19, '2-Piperidone': 22, 'Caryophyllene Oxide': 25, '\xce\xb1-Terpineol': 18, 'Linalool': 14, 'Terpinolene': 9}\r\n"
```

Comment: Because you're viewing the file with a viewer that doesn't understand utf-8?

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3 with `"default_encoding": "UTF-8"`.

`view.encoding()` reveals `UTF-8`

Comment: Instead of giving a link to an external file (which could have gone through some unexpected recoding), you could just add `print(open("log.txt", "rb").read())` immediately after your `with` block, and show us the results.  That will help us locate the encoding error, which sounds like it's at your terminal level.

Comment: Great! Please see edit #3. Thanks.

Comment: In the shell demo of EDIT #2 I think you get '?' because the terminal window can't handle the character and gives Python '?', so Python never even gets the original character. Try it in IDLE shell. Btw, if you write something like @DSM then they'll get notified.

Answer (score 1):

> "Why are these unicode key names being encoded to ascii?"

They aren't. "Encoded to ASCII" doesn't even make sense, and encoding them **using** ASCII doesn't even work:

```
>>> 'α-Terpineol'.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    'α-Terpineol'.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u03b1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looks like after the correct encoding using UTF-8, your file viewer **decoded** using ISO-8859-1 or so:

```
>>> 'α-Terpineol'.encode('utf-8').decode('ISO-8859-1')
'Î±-Terpineol'
```

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. Please see edit for link to actual txt file to verify yourself the encoding and contents. Thanks.

Comment: Google Drive Permissions Were not set properly. Now anyone with link should be able to view. Regards.